# Debian 6 - Wrong Python 2.6 Installed (have 2.6.6-8+b1, need 2.6.6-8+deb6u3)

Tags: python, debian-squeeze

On Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.10

I'm trying to install mailutils.

```
apt-get install mailutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mailutils : Depends: libmailutils2 (> 1:2.1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libpython2.6 (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

So I follow back the dependencies to python and get:

```
libpython2.6 : Depends: python2.6 (= 2.6.6-8+b1) but 2.6.6-8+deb6u3 is to be installed
```

So although it seems I have 2.6.6-8 I have the wrong variety.

I thought I might remove it and then reinstall, but no luck there either:

```
apt-get remove python2.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx-common : Depends: python but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I have also tried

```
apt-get clean && apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
aptitude reinstall python2.6
apt-get check
apt-get -f install
apt-get clean
```

Most of them a variety of times. Nothing seems to fix it.

I have pinning setup as:

```
cat /etc/apt/preferences
Package: *
Pin: release stable
Pin-Priority: 9000
```

I pinned it in order to try the upgrade and dist-upgrade.

And sources as:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# Main repo
deb http://http.debian.net/debian squeeze main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian squeeze main non-free contrib
#deb http://packages.linuxmint.com debian import

# Security
deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
```

I used the mint import to install firefox. I suspect it may have caused this install of the wrong python, actually.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any apt pining configured?  What have you configured for apt sources?  Are you really using Squeeze?  It really is past time to upgrade to a new release.

Comment: @Zoredache thanks I've updated the question. This web app requires php 5.3, hence Squeeze. I suppose I could debug it for a later version, but it's very stable as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching for `pyhton2.6` on http://packages.debian.org/ (specifically https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python2.6&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all ) shows that version 2.6.6-8+deb6u3 of python2.6 is (at time of writing this answer) is available in the squeeze-lts distribution. See https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using for instructions how to use LTS. It basically boils down to adding the following to your apt sources:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
```

After adding this and updating the list of available packages you should be able to install the specified python2.6 version using

```
aptitude install python2.6=2.6.6-8+deb6u3
```

Comment: Great, thanks! After adding that `aptitude install python2.6=2.6.6-8+deb6u3` and `aptitude install mailutils` got me the mail command

Answer (score -1):

Did you try apt-get -f install? Does that resolve it?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that. I've updated the question with the apt commands I tried. None worked.

Comment: Don't ask questions as an answer; that's what the comments are for.

Comment: Wow. Seems I clicked the wrong button. Sorry about that.